# V-Aligning with CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am creating a portfolio page for FCC and I have created a sidebar where I try to align the text so that it is in the middle. I have tried both `Verticle-Align:Middle` and `Display:Table-Cell` but neither of them are working, if anyone can help with leading me towards any other methods it would be appreciated.

```css
#sidebar > h1 {
  verticle-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="Me">
    <h1>Jake Mills</h1>
    <h2>Computing Student</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/JakeMills/full/EyWaew/

PS: I am aware I spelled `vertical` wrong in the above code. That has been corrected but still not working properly.

Comment: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Read this article, it has what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)